# how to get const MyContext = React.createContext(); for other component in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a new app using new Context API. In `MyProvider` component I get an error:

> undefined Provider.

So friends how I can achieve this `MyContext`? I created separate `.js` files and where should I place `const MyContext = React.createContext();`?

### App.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Calsi from './Calsi'
import MyProvider from './MyProvider'

const MyContext = React.createContext();


class App extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        window.MyContext = MyContext;
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <MyProvider>
                <div>
                    <Calsi/>
                </div>
            </MyProvider>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

### Calsi.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Sum from './Sum'
export  default class Calsi extends Component{
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Sum/>
            </div>
        );
    }

}
```

### Sum.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
const MyContext = window.MyContext;

export default class Sum extends Component {
    render() {

            return (
                <div>
                    <MyContext.Consumer>
                        {(context) => (
                            <React.Fragment>
                                <p>a:{context.state.a}</p>
                                <p>b:{context.state.b}</p>
                                <p>Sum: {context.state.a + context.state.b}</p>

                                <button onClick={context.increaseA}>increment a</button>
                            </React.Fragment>
                        )}
                    </MyContext.Consumer>
                </div>
            )
        }


}
```

### Provider.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
const MyContext = window.MyContext;
export default class MyProvider extends Component {

    state = {
        a: 0,
        b: 20,

    }

    render() {

            return (
                <MyContext.Provider value={{
                    state: this.state,
                    increaseA: () => this.setState({
                        a: this.state.a + 1
                    })
                }}>
                    {this.props.children}
                </MyContext.Provider>
            )
    }
}
```

I am new in react so how I can do this correctly? Also I am using react 16.3.0 alpha2 version. Thanks for your help.

Comment: why don't you try placing it in index.js!

Answer (score 1):

You have to export your context. Don't attach it to the window object of the browser (`window.MyContext = MyContext`).

Create a new file and name it `MyContext.js`.

```
export const MyContext = React.createContext();
```

Then import it in your `Provider.js`:

```
import { MyContext } from "./MyContext";
...
<MyContext.Provider value={...}>
```